# Does this series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following series as an exercise but for some reason i cannot prove if it converges or not.

I used the integral test. The series is positive and decreasing so we can use it( i will not write the proof here). That's what the theory says.

The series is the following

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n \sqrt{n+1}}$

The result i calculate is the following

$2\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{(t+1)^{3}}-\sqrt{t+1}-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{1+1}+\sqrt{1+1}=
$

$2\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{(t+1)^{3}}-\sqrt{t+1}+\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{2}$

Can someone help?

Comment: How about comparison to $n^{-3/2}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, $0<\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+1}}<\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$. Since 
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} \mathrm{d} n =
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} 2-\frac{2}{\sqrt{N}} = 2 <\infty ,
$$
we find that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ is convergent by the integral test. Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+1}}$ is convergent by the comparison test.

Comment: How did we decide to make a comparison with this.

Comment: @pleis: well, $\frac1{n\sqrt{n}}$ looks awfully like the original term, so it makes sense to start comparing with that...

Answer (score 3):

For every $n\geqslant1$,
$$\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac1{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})},
$$
and $\sqrt{n}\leqslant\sqrt{n+1}\leqslant\sqrt2\sqrt{n}$ hence
$$
\frac1{1+\sqrt2}\frac1{n\sqrt{n+1}}\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\leqslant\frac12\frac1{n\sqrt{n+1}}.
$$
This [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) has sum
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)=1,
$$
hence
$$
2\leqslant\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{n\sqrt{n+1}}\leqslant1+\sqrt2,
$$
in particular this [series with nonnegative terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29#Non-negative_terms) converges.